# Error while calling Select() in UDP sockets

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, sockets, select, visual-c++

I am doing socket programming (UDP sockets) in Windows Form application. I want to use select().

socket() is called on button click, select() is called in different thread and socket descriptor is declared global.

Below is my part of code regarding select:

```
    fd_set fds;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(s_8888, &fds);
    int n=s_8888;  //s_8888 is socket descriptor
    select (n+1, &fds, 0 , 0 , &tv );
```

When I compile my code I am getting error below

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 5 arguments
```

I am unable to understand where I have done wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have declared another variable named `select` in the context the error is given? Also, did you look up the error message's documentaton (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72c1dfd.aspx)?

Comment: @alk yes, when I comment select then there is no error

Comment: @alk I have written same code in console application it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are "shadowing" the winsock library's function `select()` by having defined another vaiable with this name.

This code

```
#include <Winsock2.h> /* Provide prototype for select(). */

void foo(void)
{
  int select;
  ...
  select(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

would provoke [error C2064](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72c1dfd.aspx) by "shadowing" the function `select()` with the variable `int select`.

To fix this rename

```
  int select;
```

to

```
  int select_whateveryoulike;
```